# How to display state values using inline if-else conditional statement in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am making money convertor in react using API. I am not sure how to display the state value using the inline if-else conditional statement in react. I know my last line of code is incorrect but this was my guess and its not working.
 My code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
        export default class App extends Component {
          constructor(){
            super();
            this.state= {
              inputAmount: 0,
              isConvert: false,
              selectedCurr: null,
              result: null,
              contryList: []
            }
            this.convertMoney= this.convertMoney.bind(this);
          }

          convertMoney(){
            fetch('https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest/')
            .then(data => {
              return data.json();
            })
            .then(result => {
              console.log(result.rates);
              let currResult = this.state.result;
              let currChange = this.state.selectedCurr;
              let inputAmt = this.state.inputAmount;
              if(currChange === "CAD"){
                currResult = inputAmt * result.rates.CAD;
              }
              else if(currChange === "INR"){
                currResult = inputAmt * result.rates.INR;
              }
              else if(currChange === "NZD"){
                currResult = inputAmt * result.rates.NZD;
              }
              else if(currChange === "AUD"){
                currResult = inputAmt * result.rates.AUD;
              }
              else if(currChange === "CZK"){
                currResult = inputAmt * result.rates.CZK;
              }
              this.setState({ 
                result: currResult.toFixed(2),
                isConvert: true
              })
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('Something bad happened!');
            })
          }

          render() {
            return (
              <div> 
               <h1>US dollar convertor</h1>
                <input 
                  type="text" 
                  value={this.state.inputAmount} 
                  placeholder = "enter US dollars" 
                  onChange={(e) => this.setState({inputAmount: e.target.value})}>
                </input>
                <select onChange = {(event) => this.setState({ selectedCurr: event.target.value})}>
                  <option> Select Curreny</option>
                  <option value="CAD">CAD</option>
                  <option value="INR">INR</option>
                  <option value="NZD">NZD</option>
                  <option value="AUD">AUD</option>
                  <option value="CZK">CZK</option>
                </select>

                <div>
                <button onClick={this.convertMoney}> convert </button>
                </div>
                <p> { this.state.isConvert ? '{this.state.selectedCurr} = {this.state.result} }' : ''}</p>
              </div>
            )
          }
        }
```

> { this.state.isConvert ? '{this.state.selectedCurr} = {this.state.result} }' : ' ' }

This line is incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). Try this:

```
{ this.state.isConvert ? `${this.state.selectedCurr} = ${this.state.result} }` : ' ' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{this.state.isConvert? <p>{this.state.selectedCurr}={this.state.result}</p>:null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you are trying to show within `<p>` tag. 
If you need to set the value of `selectedCurr` you need to use `this.setState`

```js
setSelectedCurr(curr) {
 this.setState({selectedCurr: curr});
}
```

Call this function onClick of convert button